# A TWO page single page application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm building a small search app with AngularJS and Elasticsearch and on the home page(page 1) I just have a simple header, search box and footer to start with. On the search results page(page 2) is where the results display and there are additional filters etc for the user to use.

I'm using ui-router for the routes and am having difficulty figuring out how to get page 1 to go to page 2 after the user has typed in terms or selected terms from the autocomplete dropdown.

```
    config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that my .state are wrong and need to be corrected. Update will follow soon

**UPDATED ROUTE**

```
$stateProvider
.state('search', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    '': {templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'},
    'nav@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
    'searchList@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/results.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
    'pagination@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/pagination.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'}
  }
})
```

My form on the results page (page two)

**UPDATED FORM**

```
<form ng-submit="search()" class="navbar-form" id="global-search" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="searchTerms" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Search" id="search-input" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)" autofocus>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**UPDATED INFO**
After learning of and upgrading to UI-Router(awesome), I made some different choices and changed my views. I no longer am doing a "two page SPA" but just keeping it to one page, primarily the results page. Both my homepage(formerly page one) and results page still have a search form on them and I still need to figure out how to incorporate $state.go() on my search button with ng-submit on both search forms. Currently all ng-submit does is call search().

```
$scope.search = function() {
resetResults();
$scope.filters.selectedFilters = [];

var searchTerms = $scope.searchTerms;

if (searchTerms) {
  $scope.results.searchTerms = searchTerms;
} else {
  return;
}

getResults();//uses a service to get results from search server
```

};

I'm guessing that $state.go('/search', {term: $scope.searchTerms}) should go right before getResults() ??  Still getting my head around all UI Route. Any links with working examples would be great!!

Comment: Try using `action="#/search"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `action` and `method` from the form.

When left in, angular sees those as intent to submit the form through browser default process. The `action` would then route data in form to a path on your server at `http://example.com/search`.

This would account for your server returning a 404.

Use `ng-submit` to do whatever it is your search route needs to handle the query and do something like `$state.go('/search', {term: $scope.searchTerms})`

Comment: right now my ng-submit looks like this, ng-submit="search()" - so  your saying it should look like ng-submit="search($state.go('/search', {term: $scope.searchTerms}))"

Comment: no... `search()` is a function in your controller `$scope.search = function(...` . I don't know how you have that set up currently or what your search controller expects for data

Comment: ok good, that seemed strange to me. What exactly is $state.go? And your right search() is in my controller. search() pretty much calls another function which uses a service to get the results data from ES server.

Comment: `$state.go` ..read router docs. I may be confused...is the html shown in `#/search` route? I assumed it wasn't because of the `action`

Comment: let me read up on the router docs, I was originally using ng-route and then discovered ui-router, thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: ui-router is far more robust .. defintely read docs thoroughly

Comment: please see UPDATED INFO and let me know. UI Router is great, still getting my head around all the option tho.

Comment: start a new question

Comment: didn't think about that, will do